# Getting even numbers from a list Racket

Tags: racket

I'm new in DrRacket. I have to take out all the even numbers from a list how can I do that? E.g. `(get-even-nums '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))` should return `(8 6 4 2)`.
 `(get-even-nums '(1 3 5 7 9))` should return `'()`.

```
(define(append_list list1 list2)
(cond
((null? list1) list2)
(else (even? (car list1)(cons (car list1))
           (append_list(cdr list1)) ))))
```

I really don't know how this gonna work.

Comment: You can use [`filter`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) for this. For example, `(filter even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))` will return `'(2 4 6 8)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it here is the Solution

```
(define (segregate lst)
  (let-values ([(e o) (partition even? lst)])
    (list e)))
```

Racket is not an easy language at all

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this is to simply use `filter`

Comment: Since you wrap the result in `list` you get `((8 6 4 2))` instead of `(8 6 4 2)` as by just evaluating `e`

Answer (score -1):

Following code may be simpler to understand:

```
(define (get-even-nums lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (outlst '()))
    (cond 
      [(empty? lst) 
         outlst]
      [(even? (car lst))
         (loop (cdr lst)
               (cons (car lst) outlst))]
      [else 
         (loop (cdr lst) 
               outlst)] )))
```

Ideally, one should return `(reverse outlst)` when lst is empty, but apparently you want to get even numbers in reverse order.